# VS Code: How to access debug variables from within extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am writing an extension for visual studio code where I want to evaluate the current variables of a javascript debug session. These variables are normally shown when one have open the debug pane under the section `VARIABLES`. See the attached screenshot.

[image: Debug variables pane in visual studio code]

I want to get access to these variables when the user right clicks the editor, but I don't know how.

My current extension setting for this is like that: in the `package.json` I have registered a menu contribution along with a command:

```
"contributes": {
    "menus": {
        "editor/context": [{
            "command": "extension.showVariables",
            "group": "navigation"
        }]
    }
}
```

In my extension.ts I register the command like that:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.showVariables', () => {

        // TODO: let variables = vscode.debug.activeDebugSession.variables.toString();

        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(variables);
    });
}
```

I have tried to get them through `vscode.debug.activeDebugSession` but there is no API for variables here. I also tried to register an event handler for `vscode.debug.onDidReceiveDebugSessionCustomEvent` but I can't figure out where to search for the debug variables.

Is it even possible to access these variables in an vs extension or do I need to implement my own debugger?

Comment: I just saw that I can send a `customRequest` (evaluate) to the debug adapter. But to get a local variable, I need to pass a frameId (or get the callstack/frames by passing a thread id). How do I get the thread id of the debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to get access to the local variables although this is not a general solution - it may only work in a single threaded debugger. If you know any better way, please answer or comment.

Say, the debugger breaks in a method that has a local variable `car`.

To get the value of `car`, I am using the `customRequest` method on the active debug session:

```
const session = vscode.debug.activeDebugSession;
const response = await session.customRequest('evaluate', { expression: 'car', frameId: frameId });
const car = response.result;
```

To get the frameId, I use another call of `customRequest`:

```
const session = vscode.debug.activeDebugSession;
const response = await session.customRequest('stackTrace', { threadId: 1 })
const frameId = response.stackFrames[0].id;
```

---

To get a real car object (not a string representation) in my extension, I pass `"JSON.stringify(car)"` as expression in the `evaluate` customRequest. Then, I can use `JSON.parse(response.result)`.

To get all scopes, stacks and variables, have a look at the 
[Debug Session API](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/api-debugging#_debug-session-api) and the specification of the [DebugProtocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/parts/debug/common/debugProtocol.d.ts).

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for my debug provider, I guess every debug provider can implement this feature as it wants, how did you figure out that there are `evaluate` and `stackTrace` custom requests? Do you have a documentation reference handy?

Comment: I have looked into the code and after digging found this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/blob/master/protocol/src/debugProtocol.ts#L948

Answer (score 4):

You have to talk to the debug adapter using the debug adapter protocol directly. You do it with `vscode.debug.activeDebugSession.customRequest(command: string, args?: any)` ([Ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DebugSession))

This function receives 2 parameters: command and args. Check out [this resource](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification) to find all possible values of those parameters. One example is the 'evaluate' command that **Michael Hilus** uses in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50346456/5744858):

[image]

If you want to get the variables in a multi threaded debug session, you must do these requests in this order

1. [Threads Request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Threads): Get the thread ids
2. [StackTrace Request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_StackTrace): Get the frame ids
3. [Scopes Request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Scopes): Get the variablesReference
4. [Variables Request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Variables): Finally, get the variable names with their values. If a variable is an object you might want to use [Variables Request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Variables) again with the variablesReference of the variable with an object value.

PS: It's kind of hard to find what you want in the DAP specification, so here is a tip:

1. Go to the 'Types' section in the right menu and find what you want. For instance, Breakpoints.
2. Ctrl+F and search ': Breakpoint'
3. Take a look at all matches in the response section of each request.

In the case of `variablesReference` I had to search `variablesReference: number` to find it in the responses of Evaluate Request, Scope (type) and Variable (also type).