# VS Code extension to access debug context, variables, exceptions of currently active debug session

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I'm working on a vs-code extension to deliver debug context-aware plugin, which could fetch (at least) information about current local variables, exceptions, and attribute the exception UI (nice to have). Unfortunately, both features are hard to implement without the SDK support from the vs-code sdk api.

I can access the information about an active debug session via `vscode.debug.activeDebugSession` and also execute the `customRequest` method to get more information but there is neither protocol nor documentation on how to do that:

[image]

- How can I access the $exception variable from the `Locals` variables list?
- Is it possible to customize the exception decoration UI which renders details of an error?

I discovered [this posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287482/vs-code-how-to-access-debug-variables-from-within-extension) but wasn't able to evaluate a `customRequest` for a `dotnet core` debug provider.

I have also learned [this debugger provider sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-mock-debug) to find extensibility points with no luck to solve my issue.